# how to run two functions with a delay between them

Tags: javascript, function, callback, settimeout

so I have a click event and I'm planning to change the "src" of an image tag on clicking, wait a few seconds and then change it back.....

what I've tried:

```
function(){ //getting the img
                //changing the src attribute
                
                stTimeout(someCallbackFunction()
                     { //changing src attribut once again}
                           ,3000 //waiting 3 seconds)
}
```

```
//and ofcourse eventlistener
```

but it seems like the second function isnt getting used at all and i dont know what is the problem!!

Comment: pass the reference `someCallbackFunction` not `someCallbackFunction()`.also you have a typo in setTimeout

Comment: Please, show the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supposed to look like this:

```
function funcA(){ /* code */ }

function funcB(){ 
    /* code */

    setTimeout(funcA, 3000); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have two sepearte functions you can do it like @Lynx 242 did it. If you want to specify the callback immediately do it like this:

```js
functionB(){ 
    /* code */

    setTimeout(() => {
        /* code */
    }, 3000); 
}
```